# Error with VS lib tool, "cannot open shared object file"

Tags: windows, dll, visual-studio-2012, cygwin, static-libraries

I don't have a lot of experience building libraries under Windows and I had a hard time finding info online, 'lib' and 'def' are not great search terms I expect. Anyway, my problem is shown below; although `.dll` and `.lib` files actually get built and installed, using them fails so I think I'd better solve this.  The file that lib can't find is in the directory `exports`, which is a subdirectory of the present one.  The same thing happens when I try to build a similar library (GotoBLAS).

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that it's a failure to load a .def file?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I guess I don't have a good reason, I just grabbed on to that because it was the command line argument.  I was thinking it was in some sense part of the library.  Editing accordingly.

Comment: This is what has happened. The attempt to run `lib.exe` failed, with Windows error 127, `ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND`. That means either a load time dependency could not be resolved, or a dynamic call to `GetProcAddress` failed. Because you are using cygwin it tried to turn the Windows message into something unix-like, cannot open shared object file. The .def file is a red herring.

Comment: Alright I will be looking into this...

Comment: You could perhaps use a tool like Process Monitor to diagnose the fault. Why are you using cygwin here? That sounds like it's going to lead to pain.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan 'make' doesn't work from the Visual Studio command prompt, as the Makefile invokes various unix commands like grep and uname.  Looking again though I don't think running `lib.exe` caused error 127--`lib.exe` is on the path, and when I run the command on its own from the command line, there is no error 127, just, '... no such file or directory'.  I think that might arise from a later step in the makefile.

Comment: Well you'll for sure need a real make. But surely mingw/msys has such a thing. The 127 is not that an exe or dll cannot be found. It's that a function in a dll cannot be found. So, picking up the wrong version of a dll seems likely.

Comment: You're confusing three entirely different toolchains here. Cygwin != MinGW != Visual C++. Within some pretty severe limits, you can use some things between them, but for the most part you'll save yourself a whole lot of hassle by not attempting it.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is months later but I fixed this exact issue by changing which lib.exe is on the PATH.

instead of having "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64" (or just bin or x86arm), you need to have "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\amd64"

Hope that helps you (or anyone else who finds this)

Comment: Thanks.  Part of the problem is that the amd64 directory is not installed with the VS Express edition. >:[  However it turns out that Microsoft has a very liberal definition of 'student' so I got Professional and was able to solve this problem (in a different context).